# How to update a list View Item in previous activity basing on the changes in the list view update in the next activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

I have two activity classes  Site List and Site Device list . The Site List has one field showing total number of devices in the list . The Site Device List shows all the devices in the respective site Onclick() event . Suppose i add new device to the list, How can i reflect it onto the Site List (Total number of devices)dynamically, which is my previous activity class .I have my part done upto adding new device to the list. The only thing i am left is updating the device count of the site list?

Comment: Would calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after the new device has been added not update the list for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a Listview, you just call the adapter from the corresponding class - So:
 `Site List.adapter.notifyAdapterChanged();`.

Its a bit harder if you dont post any code.

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` of the previous list view.